# jQuery focused-element highlighter, stringify attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a little script for accessibility debugging, basically I needed something that would tell me on the console which element has focus. But I dont want to know everything, just what is printed on the html. So console.log($(this)), while easy, is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Here is my code, the first function is for getting the attributes

```
(function($) {
  var _old = $.fn.attr;
  $.fn.attr = function() {
    var a, aLength, attributes, map;
    if (this[0] && arguments.length === 0) {
            map = {};
            attributes = this[0].attributes;
            aLength = attributes.length;
            for (a = 0; a < aLength; a++) {
                    map[attributes[a].name.toLowerCase()] = attributes[a].value;
            }
            return map;
    } else {
            return _old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}(jQuery));

$('*').each(function() {
  $(this).on('focus', function() {
    var attributes = JSON.stringify($(this).attr());
    var replaced = attributes
                    .replace(/{|}|,/g,' ')
                    .replace(/:/g, "=")
                    .replace(/"class"/, 'class')
                    .replace(/"id"/, 'id')
                    .replace(/"href"/, 'href')
                    .replace(/"title"/, 'title')
                    .replace(/"target"/, 'target');
    var tag = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
    console.log('<'+tag+replaced+'>...</'+tag+'>');
  });
});
```

So if my html is like

```
<a class="link" id="blue" href="w.com" target="_blank" title="vfs">link</a>
```

I get

```
<a class="link" id="blue" href="w.com" target="_blank" title="vfs">...</a>
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. The problem : as you can see the way I remove the quotes around the attributes is very bad. Unless I list every attribute possible, I will get unwanted quote marks. Any idea please ? Maybe I need to remove them before my stringification.

https://jsfiddle.net/8xnuepk9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mess about with attributes.  [Cloning](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the node, then changing the inner [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) of the clone will do what you want.

```
$('*').on('focus', function() {
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    clone.html('..')
    console.log(clone[0]);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xnuepk9/1/)

Comment: thanks I wish I found this method before (did try to look for something like that)